# Single parameter not being received in my web api 2.0 controller

Tags: c#, post, asp.net-web-api2, kendo-datasource

Background:

I am trying to send a single string to a Webapi which resides with in the same MVC application. I am using a Kendo Datasource.

Issue:

Controller function in my Web api is being contacted by my data-source call, however the parameter is coming in as null.

Various JavaScript approaches taken :

```
       var clientLookupDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        serverFiltering: true,
        transport: {
            read: {
                type: "POST",
                url: siteRoot + "api/GetClientInfo",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: function (data) {
                    return JSON.stringify({ name: "Hello World"});
                },
            }
        }
    });

      var clientLookupDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        serverFiltering: true,
        transport: {
            read: {
                type: "POST",
                url: siteRoot + "api/GetClientInfo",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: function (data) {
                    return JSON.stringify("Hello World");
                },
            }
        }
    });

        var clientLookupDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        serverFiltering: true,
        transport: {
            read: {
                type: "POST",
                url: siteRoot + "api/GetClientInfo",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: function (data) {
                    return "Hello World";
                },
            }
        }
    });
```

C# WebApi 2.0 Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/GetClientInfo")]
    public IHttpActionResult SearchClients([FromBody]string name)
    {
        return Ok("Response to" + name);
    }
```

Kendo Auto-Complete

```
             $("#clientddl").kendoAutoComplete({
                dataSource: clientLookupDataSource,
                placeholder: "Type client name...",
                filter: "contains",
                dataTextField: "ClientName",
                dataValueField: "ClientRef",
                enabled: true,
                minLength: 3,
                delay: 350,
                change: function (e) {
                    var item = this.dataItem(e.item);
                    if (item != null) {
                        JobData.ClientId = item.ClientID;
                        doClientChange(e);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: either update action to match expected complex object `class model { public string name { get; set; }}` or update JS to send just the simple string `return JSON.stringify("Hello World");`

Comment: @Nkosi I really do not want to build a data-model so I am just trying to pass a single string.  I also tried your other JavaScript approach and it also comes in as null.

Comment: Did you strinigy the simple string? I saw your update and you didn't. you just did `return "Hello World";`

Comment: Read up on this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: Yup I tried all three approaches, I posted my approaches, I can get this done by building out the url, but I feel uncomfortable doing that for this project.  That is why I want to get params from body